# Feminines oder maskulines Substantiv + „darin“

Tags: grammar, single-word-request, gender

Das Adverb „darin“ bezieht sich normalerweise nur auf Substantive, die (meines Erachtens) generell ein neutrales Genus haben.

Meine Frage ist, ob man das Wort „darin“ auch für feminine und maskuline Substantive benutzen darf. Wenn nicht, möchte ich wissen, ob es ein Wort wie „darin“ auch für das Maskulinum und Femininum gibt. „In dem“ und „in der“ sind mir bereits bekannt.

Drei Beispielsätze können vielleicht helfen:

> „Nimm das Schiff. **Darin** gibt es viel Platz.“ (Neutrum)
>   „Nimm die Banane. __ steckt viel Kalium.“ (Femininum)
>   „Nimm den Apfel. __ ist viel Vitamin C.“ (Maskulinum)

(An Lösungen, die die Beispielsätze umordnen, wie z. B. „In der Banane steckt viel Kalium; nimm sie!“, und dabei das Problem umgehen, bin ich nicht interessiert.)

Comment: Bei den Nährstoffen würde ich zu "dadrin" tendieren und genau genommen dieses separieren. "Dadrin steckt viel Kalium" oder besser "Da steckt viel Kalium drin".

Comment: Die Aussage im ersten Satz ist einfach falsch. Wo hast du das denn gehört?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Das Genus ist hier nicht der ausschlaggebende Faktor. Der erste Beispielsatz lässt sich auch mit maskulinen und femininen Substantiven bilden ohne unnatürlich oder falsch zu klingen:

> „Nimm den Wagen. Darin gibt es viel Platz.“ (maskulin)
>   „Nimm die Kutsche. Darin gibt es viel Platz.“ (feminin)

Auch in den beiden anderen Sätzen ist die Verwendung von „darin“ nicht grob falsch. Der dritte klingt zugegebenermaßen etwas unnatürlich, aber das hat vielmehr mit der Wahl des Prädikats zu tun.

In dem Pronominaladverb „darin“ steckt die Präposition „in“. Das Wort kann also nur in Bezug auf Substantive verwendet werden, die von der Bedeutungsgruppe her auch diese Präposition zulassen, also Behälter, geschlossene Orte, usw.

Natürlich gilt, wie auch für Pronomen, dass das Prädikat zu dem Bezugswort passen muss.